# Cmake configutarion file for calling a C++ code from a C++ function called by a FORTRAN code

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have been using a FORTRAN code, main.f90, to send an array to func.cpp which would call a C++ code, addition.cpp & addition.h. The code was working properly on a CentOS 4 platform, but when I moved it to a CentOS 6 one, it is giving me errors. I have tried using the same version of gcc (4.3.0) on both machines or a newer version 4.4.7 in CentOS 6, but the issue is not resolved. I am attaching the over-simplified version of the code as

main.f90:

```
 program main
   use iso_c_binding
   implicit none

   interface
      function func (a) bind (C, name="func")
         import
         integer(c_int):: func
         real(c_double), dimension(1:4), intent(in):: a
      end function func
   end interface

   real(c_double), dimension(1:4):: a = [ 2.3, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6 ]
   integer(c_int):: result
   result = func(a)
   write (*,*) result
end program main
```

func.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "addition.h"
using namespace std;

#ifdef __cplusplus
  extern"C" {
#endif

void *__gxx_personality_v0;

int func(double a[]) {
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
       cout << a[i] << endl;
   }
   int z;
   z = addition (5,3);
   cout << z << endl;
   return 0;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
  }
#endif
```

addition.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "addition.h"
using namespace std;
int addition (int a, int b)
{
 int r;
 r = a + b;
 return r;
}
```

addition.h:

```
#ifndef ADDITION_H
#define   ADDITION_H
int addition (int a, int b);
#endif /* ADDITION_H */
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
PROJECT(test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
enable_language(C Fortran)
# Setting the compilers
set (CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER /usr/bin/gfortran)
set (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/g++)
# Setting the flags
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lgfortran")
set_source_files_properties(main.f90 func.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -c)
# Making the executable
ADD_EXECUTABLE(test.exe main.f90 func.cpp addition.cpp addition.h)
```

The error I am getting now is:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [test.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.exe.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I appreciate any help on solving the issue.

Comment: from what I see in the output I could say that the problem is in the fortran "main" file. Apparently fortran code doesn't generate "main" entry point. Try to compile a simple fortran code w/o any external C++ libs and see if it works

Comment: Also I would run `make` (on the CMake-generated Makefile(s)) as `make VERBOSE=1` to see exact commands being issued by make (gcc, ld etc) and be able to reproduce the problem yourself, step by step, w/o any "buildsystem" at all, just you, the code, compiler and linker.

Comment: When I run the simple fortran code without any cpp file, it works correctly. I removed everything related to addition.cpp and addition.h, to make it simpler (so there is only call to func.cpp left); however, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Dont use fortran90 tag separately. And especially not when you use Fortran 2003 C interop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you link with `g++` when your main program is in Fortran? Do it the other way, link with `gfortran` and add `-lstdc++`.

Just add line: `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(test.exe PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE Fortran)`

Or use more recent GCC. All versions of GCC which are still supported work even with your original settings.